# How to draw an outline to an image in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone

I want to draw an outline to an image. Is there any simple way to do that in iPhone sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides drawing it urself on the screen you can maybe have an image of the outline and put 2 image views on top of each other to get the picture with it's outline

Answer (score 0):

If you have limited number of images that you need to do this with, use a drawing program to create an outlined version of each image, then use setImage: on a UIImageView to display one or the other image.

If you need to draw an outline around sone arbitrary image at run time, that's a bit harder.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Header file and also import QuartzCore.framework framework. Your job is done.

```
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"
mImage.layer.borderWidth = 2;
```